Requested location unknown after Nginx proxy_pass using URL-rewrite
I have put a PHP SPA after an Nginx reverse-proxy. The users access the application by
https://myapp.mydomain.org/staff/orders/main

Nginx forwards those requests to an internal Dockerhost running the application as container by this rule:
    location /staff/orders/ {
        proxy_pass http://apps.mydomain.int:8080/;
    }

The '/' at the end of proxy_pass directive removes the location part of the incoming request, so my app does not know how the user actually called the service.
As the app is SSO integrated, unauthorized users get redirected to our IAM and after successful authentication they should get redirected back to my app. For this the IAM needs to know the "external" URL for the redirect as the users cannot access the internal one.
But i do not find this requesting URL anywhere in the servers headers. The app is build on top of the 'php-apache' Docker image.

You can use proxy_set_header to add a custom header with a value containing the original request. Perhaps $scheme, $http_host, and $request_uri to reconstruct the original URL.

Yes, that worked! After adding:
    location /staff/orders/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Origin-Request $scheme//$host$request_uri;
        proxy_pass http://apps.mydomain.int:8080/;
    }

i can fetch the URL from $_SERVER['HTTP_X_ORIGIN_REQUEST'] in PHP code.
